# break point after attaching the debugger

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

if we attach a debugger(gdb, ida, olly... whatever) to a running process.
how can the debugger temporarily suspend the process and set a break point?

additionally, when the debugger suspends the attached process.
the debugger breaks at some library location.(such as in __kernel_vsyscall ())
but, this location is not the last EIP location when the process was running.
how can I know the last actual EIP value?

thank you in advance.

Comment: `how can the debugger temporarily suspend the process and set a break point?` As far as I know when gdb attaches to a running process it by default stops it and you can set a breakpoint. What do you mean when say `temporarily suspend the process and set a break point`?

Comment: I ment, "how can the debugger temporarily suspend the process, so that I can set a break point?" ... for example, if we attach gdb to a running process, the process stops at __kernel_vsyscall() from VDSO.

Comment: `the process stops at __kernel_vsyscall() from VDSO`. After it can you enter `break your-function-name`? I think it should set a break point. Or can you enter `finish`? `gdb` must finsih a current frame and stop again.

Comment: yes, I can enter break [funcname] or set break to any address. but, I want to know the last EIP location before the EIP came to __kernel_vsyscall() ... assume that we are debugging some unknown striped binary with PIE/ASLR enabled. that way, we don't know the memory address of any function...

Comment: OK. Can you go to an upper frame (`up`) and print EIP there (`print $eip`)? It must be EIP of the upper frame. Is it what you look for?

Comment: Wow! that's exactly what I wanted, thank you. is there a similar functionality as gdb's "up" in IDA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go to an upper frame (in gdb command: `up`) and print EIP there (in gdb command: `print $eip`)? It must be EIP of the upper frame. Remember that EIP of the upper frame will point on the intruction right AFTER the instruction that call a function.

Is it what you look for?